# How can I avoid deserealization in microservise?

Tags: performance, rest, microservices

I'm developing microservise which receives HTTP POST requests and then redirects them to another destination point in order to receive response, handle it and hand it to another system.

My question is - how can I avoid deserealization while receiving these requests? The microservice don't handle incoming JSONs. From the performance point of view, it's better to avoid deserealization.

I heard I can use Nginx or Apache but how can I embed them into the microservice?
Is there any proven solution? Just don't want to invent a bicycle.

Comment: You can use a transport format like Apache Arrow or something similar. Just look for "zero-copy"-serialization/deserialization frameworks. If you want to use json, you won't be able to remove performance costs of deserialization. It always has to happen somewhere. If not in your code, it will be somewhere in library code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the technology stack you are using (programming language, framework.. etc) but I suppose that in all of them is a way to recieve incoming rest requests without need to deserialize the body.
For example in a java/spring scenario you can define in the corresponding controller method the body parameter as string and in this case there isn't any deserialization of the body, the method will recieve it as a plain string so you can forward it as is to the other service:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path")
public ResponseEntity controllerMethod(@RequestBody String body) { 
     // your code here
}
```